# Anchored Link Scroll Interfering with the Close Function on the Menu

Tags: jquery

We're trying to get an anchored link to close the "Menu" by adding a class to the body.

The issue is that the menu has anchored links as part of the navigation.  Trying to add a function that checks for the class and then runs the toggleClass before going to the anchored link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

// Working JS that Identifies the Class and Adds the "menu_open" or toggles to Subtract
$(".menu, .arrow1, .menuAccountAccess").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('body').toggleClass('menu_open');
});

// The Main Navigation has some anchored links and the below code does not work as we also have a # link scroll code
$(".NavigationAnchoredLinkClass").on("click", function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('menu_open');
});

// Scroll function for Anchored Links  
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
            }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
 });

});
</script>

<body class="">
      <p>
      Anchored Links work fine with a <a href="#anchoredlink">Link</a>
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li class="NavigationAnchoredLinkClass">
          <a href="siteurl/#achoredlink">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: COuld you please complete HTML code, as there are few missing elements from the code like menu_open,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a check class into the anchored link scroll.  All the check class does is see if the body div has the "menu_open".  When "menu_open" is found it toggles the class to blank which then closes the menu as another function runs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {

    // checks body for class
     if ($('body').hasClass('menu_open')) {
         // if class is found it toggles the class to blank which closes the menu
         $('body').toggleClass('menu_open');
     }

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60

      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

});

});